# In Scala templates, how do I end a variable without a space?

Tags: java, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I need to make a quick change to a page built in Scala in a Play app. Not really sure how to do this...

I have a variable @name that contains "foo" and I want to do this:

```
<div id="@name" class="@name_class">
```

and have it resolve to

```
<div id="foo" class="foo_class">
```

however Play is trying to look for a variable named @name_class

Comment: `@(name)_class` as expression.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can avoid a temporary variable with the following:

```
<div id="@name" class="@{name}_class"> ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first concatenate the string and the display:

```
@val class_name = name + "_class"
```

And then assign:

```
<div id="@name" class="@class_name">
```

**EDIT**

As explained in the comment by @Chirlo the above will not work as of Play 2.1
you can put concatenation in a reusable block and use as such:

```
@mkClassString(name:String,tag:String):String = { name + tag }
```

and use it:

```
<div id="@name" class="@mkClassString(name,"_class")">
```

or use `@defining` as indicated by comment.

Comment: This wont' compile (as of Play 2.1.0), you'd need to write  `@defining( name +"_class") { class_name => <div id="@name" class="@class_name"> }`. See [Declaring reusable values](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/ScalaTemplates)

Answer (score 0):

You can enclose with parenthesis, I haven't really tested with curly braces.

```
<div id="@name" class="@(name)_class"> ...
```